# Kernel didn't update to the latest version in Debian

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, upgrade

I saw this security vulnerability on the Debian website: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-5754

```
stretch (security)  4.9.65-3+deb9u2 fixed
```

I tried to update it using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The output was:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-compiler-gcc-6-x86_4.9.65-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-compiler-gcc-6-x86 (4.9.65-3+deb9u2) over (4.9.65-3+deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-kbuild-4.9_4.9.65-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-kbuild-4.9 (4.9.65-3+deb9u2) over (4.9.65-3+deb9u1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_4.9.65-3+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.9.65-3+deb9u2) over (4.9.65-3+deb9u1) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.9.65-3+deb9u2) ...
Setting up linux-compiler-gcc-6-x86 (4.9.65-3+deb9u2) ...
Setting up linux-kbuild-4.9 (4.9.65-3+deb9u2) ...
```

The output for `uname -a` is:

```
4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output when I used `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` was `4.9.65-3+deb9u2`, but in `uname -a` it's `4.9.65-3+deb9u1`. Why didn't the kernel update to the latest version?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the latest [`linux-image`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64) including the security updates as follows :

```
apt install linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64
```

Reboot your system.

```
uname -a
4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This update will be available through the regular update from the security repository , this a sample [`sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList):

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
```

The fix is available for debian Sid but the updates cannot be applied through the regular update it appear a bug affecting the `unattended-upgrades` package, see the [@sampablokuper question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414991/unattended-upgrades-not-detecting-linux-kernel-security-update-by-default) and the new report bug  [#886415](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=886415)

To apply the security update on debian Sid:

```
apt install linux-image-4.14.0-3-amd64
```

Comment: if there are any dkms modules (e.g. `nvidia-kernel-dkms`, `spl-dkms` and `zfs-dkms`, `virtualbox-dkms`) installed, the matching linux-headers- package should be installed too.   i.e.  `apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-5-amd64 linux-headers-4.9.0-5-amd64`

Answer (score 2):

Did you restart your computer? Most updates are applied without problem without need of restart but that's not the case of kernel updates.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
```

The recommended instructions did not work for me:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

I got:

```
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-image-amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apt upgrade` instead of `apt-get upgrade`. Did the trick for me and installed latest kernel.

Answer (score -1):

snowflake@safespaces:/home/snowflake# **uname --all -p -i**
Linux safespaces **4.9.0-5-amd64** #1 SMP Debian **4.9.65-3+deb9u2** (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

HELLO!
i got this on mine after running this cmd
'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'

and just to make sure it upped it i ran this:
**uname --all -p -i** 
and got this
Linux safespaces **4.9.0-5-amd64** #1 SMP Debian **4.9.65-3+deb9u2** (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

so i'd say it's working, and this is just a vbox vm